# 1 and 7 are mixed up in the textbox and textblock in the entire wpf aapplication

Tags: fonts, wpf-controls, truetype, wpf-positioning

In my Wpf application when ever 1 and 7 appears adjacently like 178 or 217 in the textbox or textblock they are mixed up. Thanks for any help in advance

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't see your screen or read your code from here, and it's very unclear what your problem is, and there's not nearly enough information provided for us to be able to answer it. You're going to need to [edit] your question and provide a lot more information (including a snippet of relevant code) about the problem before we'll be able to help.

Comment: <TextBox Text = "178"/> this appears like 1 and 7 are clumsy. This happening for the entire project.

Comment: I am Using Custom Fonts, Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE Medium.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Try setting on your textbox the following option `UseLayoutRounding=True`. That might help

EDIT:
try this link:
http://geekswithblogs.net/Martinez/archive/2010/01/29/custom-font-in-wpf-application.aspx